# How to update a row omitting a column in Slick 3.x?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following code in Slick that updates an object user:

```
val users = TableQuery[UserDB]
val action = users.filter(_.id === user.id).update(user)
val future = db.run(action)
val result = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```

But there's a field in the user object (password) that I don't want to update. How to omit it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should select columns using a `map` operation before an `update` operation:

```scala
case class User(name: String, age: Int, password: String, id: Int)

val updatedUser = User("Pawel", 25, "topsecret", 123)
val users = TableQuery[UserDB]
val action = users.filter(_.id === updatedUser.id).map(user => 
  (user.name, user.age)
).update(
  (updatedUser.name, updatedUser.age)
)
val future = db.run(action)
val result = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```