# Can Slick's insertOrUpdate modify a subset of columns in the event the record already exists?

Tags: sql, scala, slick, upsert

In my use case I have a `createdDate` field that I would like to preserve in the event that the record already exists.

```
case class Record(id:Long, value:String, createdDate:DateTime, updateDate:DateTime)
```

Is it possible to use a TableQuery.insertOrUpdate(record) such that only parts of the record are updated in the event the record already exists?

In my case I'd want only the `value` and `updateDate` fields to change. Using plain SQL in a stored procedure I'd do something like:

```
merge Record r
using (
    select @id,
           @value
) as source (
    id,
    value
)
on r.id = source.id
when matched then 
    update set value = source.value, updateDate = getDate()
when not matched then 
    insert (id, value, createdDate, updatedDate) values
    (id, value, getDate(), getDate()
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? I am running into the same issue, and the only work-around I see so far is not using `insertOrUpdate` and switching to writing my own upsert logic.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Slick's `insertOrUpdate` modify a subset of columns?

No, I don't believe this is possible with the `insertOrUpdate` function. This has been [requested as a feature](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1190) but it is not currently implemented.

**How can we work around this?**

Since [the `update` function does support updating a specific list of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37572062/346561), we can write our own upsert logic instead of using the `insertOrUpdate` function. It might work like this:

```
def insertOrUpdate(record: Record): Future[Int] = {
  val insertOrUpdateAction = for {
    recordOpt <- records.filter(_.id === record.id).result.headOption
    updateAction = recordOpt.map(_ => updateRecord(record))
    action <- updateAction.getOrElse(insertRecord(record))
  } yield action
  connection.run(insertOrUpdateAction)
}

private def updateRecord(record: Record) = {
  val query = for {
    r <- records.filter(_.id === record.id)
  } yield (r.value, r.updatedDate) // list of columns which can be updated
  query.update(record.value, record.updatedDate)
}

private def insertRecord(record: Record) = records += record
```